# Why has NASA shunned the worm logo?

Tags: nasa, insignia

I *love* the NASA "worm" logo.  It's a futuristic, stylish rendering of the agency's acronym.  But they ["retired"](https://www.nasa.gov/audience/forstudents/5-8/features/symbols-of-nasa.html) it in 1992.  ***WHY???***

[image: NASA worm logo]

It was replaced with NASA's original logo, the ["meatball"](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/5739/26446):

[image: NASA meatball logo]

Not be confused with the NASA seal, which is supposed to be used only by NASA's administrator:

[image: NASA seal]

Comment: same reason disco was "replaced"? Also, it's always dangerous to try to look "modern" (e.g. modern architecture and [these](https://www.sadanduseless.com/funny-80s-hairstyles/))

Comment: @uhoh: Hey, I used to... oh, never mind.

Comment: Those look like the haircuts of intrepid space colony dwellers whose souls are not tied down by gravity.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because NASA Administrator Dan Goldin [didn't like it](https://www.sun-sentinel.com/news/fl-xpm-1992-05-23-9202090944-story.html).

> After hearing complaints from employees across the nation, new NASA
>   Administrator Daniel S. Goldin announced unexpectedly on Friday that
>   he was changing the agency's logo. Goldin killed the despised "worm,"
>   which spelled out "NASA" in high-tech red lettering, and restored the
>   insignia affectionately known as the "meatball."

(Personal note: many employees at the time would have taken issue with the veracity of the claims in this quote - that they "despised" the worm and were clamoring to replace it.)

But he loved that meatball logo.  You can see in this picture how much he loved that meatball logo.

[image]

PS the aircraft in the picture is the first Boeing 737 ever built, which served as a research aircraft at NASA-Langley for years. It's now in the Museum of Flight, and ironically has a worm on its tail.  And that is an air data probe.

[image]

Image [source](https://www.jetphotos.com/photo/8779991)

Comment: I've just asked [How did NASA Langley end up with the first 737?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/64582/14213) Feel free to edit it or let me know if needs editing or if linking here is awkward. Thanks!

Comment: That skinny, low-bypass engine....

Comment: Not that airplanes are LEGO elements, but it'd be amusing to see someone try to build one with a GE9X engine: https://s3.amazonaws.com/dsg.files.app.content.prod/gereports/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/15134449/GE9X-FTB-Takeoff-6x4_2_small.jpg

Comment: It's a JT8D...it would hardly count as a turbo*fan* these days!  Bypass ratio of 1! That GE9X is 10.

Comment: First time I saw the GE9X, my thought was, "I didn't even know airplanes could be stung by bees!"

Comment: I think they'd have to do like the Hondajet and put the engines above the wing. https://cdn.avbuyer.com/uploads/cms_article/112001_112100/112050_1269_969X727.jpg